# Function swapExactTokensForETH Not Work For me only since MY CONTRACT

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, uniswap, swaps

I have a written contract in which I use functions like swapExactETHForTokens in a payable way. This one works for me.

When I try to execute the non-payable function of swapExactTokensForETH from my own contract, I get a "Fail" error, I can't find the reason for this whole thing.

My solidity code:

```
/* DEVELOP --> */
function swapExactTokensForETHOwn(address _tokenIn , uint256 _amountIn , uint256 _amountOutMin, uint256 deadline, address _contractAddress) external {

    IERC20 erc20 = IERC20(_tokenIn);

    erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, _contractAddress, _amountIn);
    erc20.approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, _amountIn);
    //IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, ContractAddr , amountIn);
    // require( IERC20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, _contractAddress, _amountIn) , 'TransferFrom failed.');
    // require( IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, _amountIn) , 'Aprove failed' );

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = _tokenIn;
    path[1] = WETHR;

    uniswap.swapExactTokensForETH(
        _amountIn,
        _amountOutMin,
        path,
        msg.sender,
        deadline
    );

}
```

My code in Javascript:

```
try {

        // TRANSACTION REALIZATE 
        let qtyOutputMin = Math.pow(10, 18)*0.180053; // calculate manual // change and operate with usdc // OUTPUT TOKEN QUANTITY 
        let qtyInputMin = web3.utils.toHex("100000000000000000000"); 
        const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10; // 20 minutes from the current Unix time
        // calculatePriceOfGas();
        // function (address _tokenIn ,uint256 _amountOutMin, uint256 _amountIn, uint256 deadline, address _contractAddress)
        var swap = tokenSwapContract.methods.swapExactTokensForETHOwn(_tokenIn, qtyInputMin, web3.utils.toHex("0") , deadline, personalContractAddress)

        var encodedABI = swap.encodeABI()
        var tx = {
            from: activeAccount.address, 
            to: personalContractAddress,
            gas: 392671,
            gasPrice: 30000000000,
            data: encodedABI
        };
        var signedTx = await activeAccount.signTransaction(tx)
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
        .on('transactionHash', function(hash) {
            console.log("transactionHash", hash);
        })
        .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt) {
            console.log("confirmation", confirmationNumber, receipt); 
            const gasUsed = tx.receipt.gasUsed;
            console.log("Gas Used in Transaction --> " + gasUsed);
        })
        .on('receipt', function(receipt) {
            console.log("receipt" , receipt);
            return receipt;
            // logic here --> 
            // recepti** 
        })
        .on('error', function(error, receipt) { // If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the second parameter will be the receipt.
            console.error("Error:", error, "Receipt:", receipt)
        });
        
    } 
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

As I mentioned I have other functions in my contract, only payable ones like "swapExactETHForTokens" work for me. When I try to exchange tokens for ETH I can't get it to work

I also tried to run the function outside of my contract using Uniswap's own and it worked fine. When I erase the lines

```
 IERC20 erc20 = IERC20(_tokenIn);
    erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, _contractAddress, _amountIn);
    erc20.approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, _amountIn);
```

The error I get is: Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED',
When I have them the error is the following: Error: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Here examples with approve and without approve: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xce81e4d043ca8345dba4a9c94736074725ec6eca3f785888f5a4ae5111c684a9
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x367fb91ee0a37d4b4f7fc535d48cfce487cc5d99e18dd0040d103dcfbb0aab81

Any extra information I can provide.

Thank you

versions:
Truffle v5.3.10 (core: 5.3.10)
Solidity - ^ 0.7.0 (solc-js)
Node v14.15.4
Web3.js v1.3.6

Comment: You have not approved correct amount of tokens for the swap.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. in this case I am pass a DAI token amount. Do you mean that the amount spent is in bad format?

Comment: I changed to ether js library and approve tokens from js and after since solidity. resolve.

Comment: @AlvaroHeras It will be nice if you can write the solution as answer so this question can be marked as resolved and it will help others in similar situation.

Comment: @AlvaroHeras It would be bice if you can add as answer a few lines describing the solution so you can mark the question as resolved.